# What type of weaponry with the minimal amount of force would be appropriate to kill and subdue a superhuman?

Tags: weapons, super-powers, combat, firearms

I know this question might seem a bit vague so I hope to clarify here.

Say, an individual, or group of individuals, is tasked to kill several superheroes/villains with superhuman physical characteristics. What weapons/ammo would they use to kill them with **minimal collateral damage** and **minimal non-combatant casualties**?

(These tools can be fictional or currently existing but they must not be *"magical"*. Think more Gears of War/Mass Effect instead of Skyrim/Dragon age. Please detail the function and ammunition of the weapon.)

**Target 1-** Strength/Durability **10x** average adult male. 
*(can lift 3/4 short ton over head = 1,550 lbs)*

**Target 2-** Strength/Durability **50x** average adult male. 
*(can lift near 4 tons over head = 7,750 lbs)*

**Target 3-** Strength/Durability **500x** average adult male.
*(can lift near 40 tons over head = 77,500 lbs)*

**Target 4-** Strength/Durability **5000x** average adult male. *(can lift near 400 tons = 775,000 lbs)*

**Target 5-** Strength/Durability **50000x** average adult male. *(can lift near 4000 tons = 7,750,000 lbs)*

Edit: As I was asked to quantify what exactly I meant by durability, I will. Logically, characters capable of physically achieving a certain degree of energy output, must be able to at least withstand a comparable amount of damage, or their bodies would break apart from the strain and automatic counterforce, whenever they exert themselves.

As such, assume **Target 1** possesses skin with the durability of well-treated leather and while a gunshot from a 9mm would bruise, it would not penetrate the skin. Simply scale up from there.

In addition, assume that as the potency of their superhuman characterisitics increase, their vulnerability to certain other weaknesses would lessen as well. This would include mundane poison, blunt force trauma and radiation. Fall damage would be less of a problem, considering their bodies are already ignoring physics in the sense that their radical strength doesn't already tear them apart.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding. What about tranquilizer darts or poison? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: could you please specify what you mean by durability? human durability is a rather exotic quantity and I think most people here will find it hard to grasp what 500x the average human durability actually is.

Comment: Their strength (as measured by their ability to lift a weight over their head) has little to do with how vulnerable they are to standard weaponry. Is there any reason why a single well placed bullet would not kill them?

Comment: I can't seem to get 400 tons = 777,500 lbs no matter which I use (tonne/US ton/Imp ton).

Comment: A quick back of the envelope calculation shows that for target 4, most solid objects would not be able to resist the pressure exerted by 400 tonnes spread over 2 hands.

Comment: If you're asking for hard science answers you should provide us hard science knowledge on how durable they are. Is their skin durable or are they resilient to blunt force trauma?

Comment: Note that the [hard-science] tag places very specific restrictions on answers. If you don't actually want that, consider at least removing that tag; if you do want hard-science answers, then the question needs to live up to hard-science rigor itself.

Comment: 1. This _question_ is not hard science, so it can't be answered with hard science (anytime you're "ignoring physics", you're going to have a science problem). 2. This question is _far_ too broad; Worldbuilding.SE is much better suited to answering _narrow_ and _specific_ questions, and this is an "idea generation" question. 3. Partially because this question is so broad, it's also _primarily opinion based_. Any number of solutions are available without a clear, _objective_ way to evaluate between them.

Comment: @Azuaron I removed the hard science tag. I hadn't given it much thought when I tagged it and realized the mistake later.

Comment: @Aron I simply scaled up from the original target, so the **near** 400 tons was simply because of how I began

Comment: @ZinoA The only difference between the `hard-science` and `science-based` tags is that `hard-science` requires citations; `science-based` still requires hard science. From the tag description: "For questions that require answers **based on hard science**, not magic or pseudo-science, but do not require scientific citations." (em. mine)

Comment: @Azuaron, I'll remove it then. I wasn't aware that was how it worked. This is my first question.

Answer (score 5):

Your superhumans are characterized by higher levels of strength and durability. This suggests standard munitions could be used against them. Although, scaled up in terms of penetrating power because the strength of materials constituting their bodies will also increase to compensate for the stresses entailed in exerting their greater levels of strengths.

No magic bullets are required. Just more high-powered ones. Probably, with higher velocities to give the punch of higher kinetic energy to penetrate their superhuman flesh.

Appropriate weapons and their bullets would need to be chosen for each of the four targets.

Comment: I would suggest that a standard bullet can do damage in excess 50x human durability. A few seconds with a 50cal probably does in excess of 5000x human durability, it certainly makes a mess of anything else.

Comment: @Separatrix Good to have your input. I don't have expertise in the damage to the human body caused by bullets, but from what little I know it seemed probable that existing guns were lethal enough for these superhumans.

Answer (score 3):

### Asphyxia

No matter how thick their skin is (I assume this is what you meant by durability), everyone has to breath. Just throw them some can filled with a really bad volatile chemical agent (we're really good at creating horrifying gases...) and watch them melt from the inside. Alternatively, if you can lock them in a room, deprive it from O² (inject CO², CO or N², you name it) and you're set.

### Poison

I assume no dart will pass their skin, but they should still eat. As a stealthy approach, poison their food ! Again, we're really good at creating horrifying poisons.

### Radioactive dust

A variant from the evil gases approach : evil radioactive dust. Once in the respiratory system, them little nasties will kill your super-human from the inside. KGB approves.

### Heavy weaponry

A little dull, but why not. Instead of a gun, carry a rocket launcher. Or a tank. Or a rack of missiles launcher. Just do this in a non populated area, to keep the collateral damage actually minimal.

### Lasers !

We have powerful lasers. Your super-human has eyes. At the very least you can blind him. Best case scenario is you fry his brain.

### Make them fall

No matter how strong, what kills in a fall is the brutal deceleration of impact wich applies to all of the body. Event if their bones are adamantium grade and their skin can withstand any blow, their organs and brain will still be squished by the sudden and unavoidable deceleration.

### Make them drown

Which is basically asphyxia by water. Offer your super-humans some cement shoes and big lead "jewelry" and throw them in the ocean. Huge strength won't make a great difference in swimming ability.

Really, in all these cases, the dose makes it all. You can always use more poison, deadlier gases, heavier weaponry, more powerful lasers. It's all a matter of *"can your guys have these"*, but I assume since they're specifically tasked to kill the supervillains, they have enough ressources available to them.